# Как записать свою структуру в QDataStream?

Tags: c++, qt

Всем привет, имеется структура

```
struct data{
QString engRegion;
QString rusRegion;
//..
}
```

Пытался записывать данные следующим образом:

```
data test;
//..
QFile f("D:\\test.json");
f.open(QFile::WriteOnly);
QDataStream out(&f);
out << test;
```

Но к сожалению так не работает. Так каким образом можно записывать структуру в файл? Очень надеюсь на вашу помощь, заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Нужно перегрузить операторы `<<` и `>>` для вашей структуры для `QDataStream`. Что-то вроде того:

```
QDataStream &operator <<(QDataStream &stream, const data &A){
    stream << engRegion;
    stream << rusRegion;
    ...
    return stream;
}
QDataStream &operator >>(QDataStream &stream, data &A){
    stream >> engRegion;
    stream >> rusRegion;
    ...
    return stream;
}
```

Comment: благодарю, ранее видел такой способ, но не знал как применить. Сейчас всё удалось. А обязательно каждый раз писать A.engRegion и т.д. или есть что-то на подобии with из delphi?

Comment: @Malice,  не понял вопроса, уточните, пожалуйста